# Compilation error in eclipse [counterclockwise plugin]

Tags: clojure, eclipse-plugin, counterclockwise

I am getting this error whenever i try to run project.clj file:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defproject in this context,
```

I figured it out that the problem is with leiningen as i am also not able to create any projects in repl as well:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: lein in this context,
```

Thought there might be a problem with counterclockwise plugin and re-installed, but same error.

Comment: Does leningen run ok in your shell?

Comment: No..it is not running.

Comment: What is the error when you run lein in shell?

Comment: `Unable to resolve symbol: lein in this context` this is what i am getting